# Converting from class to functional component with async state setting

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-hooks, asynccallback

I have a simple class-based component that I'm trying to convert to a function-based component, but am running into all kinds of dead ends.

My component is a straightforward adaptation of the boilerplate `gifted-chat` package, and uses Watson Assistant as a backend to provide responses. There's nothing complex about the backend part, these are just thin wrappers on Watson Assistants's API:

```
getSessionID = async (): Promise<string>
```

gets a session ID for use in communicating with the backend, and

```
sendReply = async (reply: string, sessionID: string): Promise<string>
```

returns Assistant's response to the string provided as a `reply`. These are not the source of the trouble I'm having (the bodies of both could be replaced with `return await "some string"` and I'd have the same issues): the class-based version (below) works perfectly.

But I'm at a loss to figure out how to convert this to a functional form, in particular:

1. I'm struggling to find a suitable replacement for `componentWillMount`. Using `useEffect` with `sessionID` as state results in errors: `getMessage` gets called (even if I `await`) before the required sessionID is set.

I can avoid this by not making sessionID state (which it arguably shouldn't be) and just making it a global (as in the functional attempt below). But even if I do this:

2. After each user reply, and receipt of a response, the user reply is removed from the conversation, so that the entire conversation just consists of generated replies.

Both of these problems are, I think, linked to the lack of callbacks in the hook-based state setting idiom, but the issue could also lie elsewhere. In any case, I'm at a loss to know what to do.

---

**Chatter.tsx** (working class based version)

```
import React from 'react'
import { GiftedChat } from 'react-native-gifted-chat'
import WatsonAssistant from "../services/WatsonAssistant"



class Chatter extends React.Component {
    state = {
        messages: [],
        sessionID: null,
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        WatsonAssistant.getSessionID()
            .then((sID) => {    
                this.setState( {
                    sessionID: sID,
                } )    
            } )
            .then(() => this.getMessage(''))
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error)
            } )
    }

    onSend = (message = []): void => {
        this.setState((previousState) => ( {
            messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, message),
        } ), () => {
            this.getMessage(message[0].text.replace(/[\n\r]+/g, ' '))
        } )
    }

    getMessage = async (text: string): Promise<void> => {
        let response = await WatsonAssistant.sendReply(text, this.state.sessionID)
        let message = {
            _id: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000).toString(),
            text: response,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            user: {
                _id: '2',
                name: 'Watson Assistant',
            },
        }
        this.setState((previousState) => ( {
            messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, message),
        } ))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <GiftedChat
                messages={ this.state.messages }
                onSend={ messages => this.onSend(messages) }
                user={ {
                    _id: 1,
                } }
            />
        )
    }
}

export default Chatter
```

**Chatter.tsx** (failed function based attempt)

```
import React, {FC, ReactElement, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { GiftedChat } from 'react-native-gifted-chat'
import WatsonAssistant from "../services/WatsonAssistant"

let sessionID: string

const Chatter: FC = (): ReactElement => {

    const [ messages, setMessages ] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            WatsonAssistant.getSessionID()
                .then(sID => sessionID = sID )
                .then(() => getMessage(''))
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error)
                } )
        }
        fetchData()
    }, [ ])

    const onSend = async (message = []) => {
        const newMessages = await GiftedChat.append(messages, message)
        await setMessages(newMessages)
        await getMessage(message[0].text.replace(/[\n\r]+/g, ' '))
    }

    const getMessage = async (text: string): Promise<void> => {
        let response = await WatsonAssistant.sendReply(text, sessionID)
        let message = {
            _id: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000).toString(),
            text: response,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            user: {
                _id: '2',
                name: 'Watson Assistant',
            },
        }
        await setMessages(await GiftedChat.append(messages, message))
    }


    return (
        <GiftedChat
            messages={ messages }
            onSend={ messages => onSend(messages) }
            user={ {
                _id: 1,
            } }
        />
    )

}

export default Chatter
```

**Chatter.tsx** (working function based version)

```
import React, {FC, ReactElement, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { GiftedChat } from 'react-native-gifted-chat'
import WatsonAssistant from "../services/WatsonAssistant"

let sessionID: string

const Chatter: FC = (): ReactElement => {

    const [ messages, setMessages ] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            WatsonAssistant.getSessionID()
                .then(sID => sessionID = sID )
                .then(() => getMessage('', []))
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error)
                } )
        }
        fetchData()
    }, [ ])

    const onSend = async (message = []) => {
        const newMessages = await GiftedChat.append(messages, message)
        await setMessages(newMessages)   // Apparently, no waiting goes on here
        await getMessage(message[0].text.replace(/[\n\r]+/g, ' '), newMessages)
    }

    const getMessage = async (text: string, currentMessages): Promise<void> => {
        let response = await WatsonAssistant.sendReply(text, sessionID)
        let message = {
            _id: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000).toString(),
            text: response,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            user: {
                _id: '2',
                name: 'Watson Assistant',
            },
        }
        await setMessages(await GiftedChat.append(currentMessages, message))
    }


    return (
        <GiftedChat
            messages={ messages }
            onSend={ messages => onSend(messages) }
            user={ {
                _id: 1,
            } }
        />
    )

}

export default Chatter
```

Comment: _(Note: I'm new to all of this, so may be missing some basics.)_

Comment: Not an answer but try moving everything over useEffect. Also try to set `sessionID` to a state (as you have in the class based) and then listen with another useEffect to this change to then trigger `getMessage`.

Comment: @Alvaro I'm also looking at [`react-usestate-callback`](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-usestate-callback). Is there any reason to avoid just doing that?

Comment: @orome because useStateFromCallback is just an equivalent of `useState` and `useEffect(foobar, [myStateValue])` as you can see in the library's source code: https://github.com/the-road-to-learn-react/use-state-with-callback/blob/master/src/index.js

Comment: @VictorLevasseur Ah, indeed, I see. That won't help me I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, since I don't have your full code I'm not sure this will just work as-is (in particular without the types from your dependencies I'm not sure if/how much the compiler will complain), but should give you something you can adapt easily enough.

```
const reducer = ({ messages }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'add message':
      return {
        messages: GiftedChat.append(messages, action.message),
      };

    case 'add sent message':
      return {
        // Not sure if .append is variadic, may need to adapt
        messages: GiftedChat.append(messages, action.message, action.message[0].text.replace(/[\n\r]+/g, ' ')),
      }
  }
};

const Chatter = () => {
  const [sessionID, setSessionID] = useState(null);
  const [messages, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, []);

  const getMessage = async (text: string, sessionID: number, type: string = 'add message'): Promise<void> => {
    const response = await WatsonAssistant.sendReply(text, sessionID);
    const message = {
      _id: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000).toString(),
      text: response,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      user: {
        _id: '2',
        name: 'Watson Assistant',
      },
    };

    dispatch({
      type,
      message,
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      WatsonAssistant.getSessionID()
        .then(sID => (setSessionID(sID), sID))
        .then(sID => getMessage('', sID))
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error)
        });
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <GiftedChat
      messages={messages}
      onSend={messages => getMessage(messages, sessionID, 'add sent message')}
      user={{
        _id: 1,
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Main difference is `useReducer`. As far as I can tell in the original code you had two actions: append this message or append this message and then a copy of it with the text regex replaced. I've used different dispatches to the reducer to handle the cases rather than the callback to `setState`. I've modified your attempt at `useEffect`, here I'm (ab)using the comma operator to return the ID returned from the service so that it can be fed directly to `getMessage` as a parameter rather than relying on state that hasn't been updated yet.

I'm still kinda skeptical in general about the hooks API, but assuming this works I actually think it simplifies the code here.

Comment: Why not assign `sessionID` to a ref and set it in `then()`? This way we don't need to pass it as an argument to `getMessage` and, as far as I understand, it wouldn't affect anything else.

Comment: That's an interesting approach (I can't quite get it to work, but I'll give it a shot). But the more interesting part of you'r answer is "I'm still kinda skeptical in general about the hooks API". What is the point of hooks and the move from to functional components. In a case like this, the class based component is much easier to understand and manage; the functional version is just confusing.

Comment: @Alvaro that would probably work since you only set it once on mount and it never changes.

Comment: @orome I think the one I'm really skeptical about is `useEffect`. All of the other ones seem pretty straightforward and I'm especially fond of state, reducer, and context. But its really, really hard (at least for me, at least for now) to get the semantics of `useEffect` correct. It runs when I don't want it to, it doesn't run when I do want it to, and half the time it enters an infinite re-render loop. I suspect that it's *too* powerful/flexible and therefor the API is too weird.

Comment: Note that I can get my functional version to work fine if I add an argument to `getMessage` for just-updated messages, passing the result of `GiftedChat.append(messages, message)` as a value in `onSend`. My issue I think boils down to either my `await` on `setMessages`  having no effect, or that `setMessages` triggers a side effect that messes me up. Either way, without the change, the subsequent `getMessage` inside `onSend` uses the old state, unless the new messages (not messages state) is passed as an argument. (Not that I understand any of that.)

Comment: @orome setting state (either way) doesn't return a Promise (and they refused to alter it to do so because of good reasons I don't recall off the top of my head, there's a [github thread](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2642) if you're interested). So there's no way to `await` the state change, that's what the callback parameter/componentDidUpdate were for. You can simulate it with `useEffect` but it's not necessarily clear that you need to here.

Comment: @JaredSmith Yeah, I think that's what this boils down to. I set state and then immediately rely on it (before it has actually changed) so unless I explicitly pass the value I've used also just passed to `setMessages` as the first argument to `GiftedChat.append`, I'm (likely) using state that hasn't been updated.